# Exposing tags to Google Scholar

Tags: metadata

I want Google Scholar to detect and consider academic papers on my website. I implemented tags as required in [http://scholar.google.com/intl/en/scholar/inclusion.html], time passed (more than 3 months), and they still ignoring my metadata. I checked over and over, and nothing happens... any ideas on how to check this in a realistic way?

Google says some of they refresh takes more than a year.... it is dumb to wait a year to notice there was a bug... and then again wait for another year...

Comment: Have you tried to contact Google Scholar directly? I have worked with Google Scholar a couple of times over the years and have found them to be extremely helpful and responsive. My impression is that it's not a very big team, so perhaps your message fell through the cracks?

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problems with Google Scholar. Unfortunately, there isn't much you can do. GS support isn't helpful at all, and indexing **can** take that much time. Sorry.